# why is kafka-producer-perf-test.sh throwing error?

Tags: apache-kafka

kafka-producer-perf-test.sh throwing corrupt message error and not producing any results. What's the reason.

I am trying to run a performance test on my Kafka cluster using the shell scripts provided with Kafka, It is generating CORRUPT_MESSAGE ERROR.

`Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)
[2019-01-03 10:33:09,119] WARN [Producer clientId=producer-1] Got error produce response with correlation id 2396 on topic-partition my_topic-1, retrying (2147483519 attempts left). Error: CORRUPT_MESSAGE (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender)`

I am running the following command to run the test

```
bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --topic my_topic --num-records 50 --throughput 10 --producer-props bootstrap.servers=kafka1:9092 key.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer value.serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer --record-size 1
```

What could be the reason behind this?

Edit 1:

We have a cluster of 5 brokers r5.xlarge machines (4 cores, 32 GB RAM) with heap option Xmx3G.

Comment: Your Kafka version?

Comment: The latest one 2.1

Comment: Can you confirm both the client and brokers are running Kafka 2.1?

Comment: yes. all the brokers and the client are running latest kafka version 2.1

Comment: has you enought memory in all nodes ?

Comment: Yes... We are using r5.xlarge machines for our brokers which has 32 GB of RAM. Also, we have set the heap size to 3 GB for the java application.